# How to store an array returned by a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, programming-languages, methods

I want to store the array returned by a method into another array. How can I do this?

```
public int[] method(){
    int z[] = {1,2,3,5};
    return z;
}
```

When I call this method, how can I store the returned array (z) into another array?

Comment: Do you mean copying the array, or just assigning the result of this method to a variable so you can use it?

Comment: Do you mean appending the results onto another array? As in, you started with foo = { 9, 9, 9 }, then after calling your method you want to append them to foo such that foo becomes { 9, 9, 9, 1, 2, 3, 5 }?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public int[] method() {
    int z[] = {1,2,3,5};
    return z;
}
```

The above method does not return an array par se, instead it returns a reference to the array. In the calling function you can collect this return value in another reference like:

```
int []copy = method();
```

After this `copy` will also refer to the same array that `z` was refering to before.

If this is not what you want and you want to create a copy of the array you can create a copy using `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] x = method();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, int[] x = method(); worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Is this equally valid? int [] x;   x = method():

Answer (score 4):

int[] anotherArray = method();

Do you want to make another physical copy of the array ?

Then use

```
System.arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate the array, you can use [`copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

Try :-

```
int arr[]=mymethod();

//caling method it stores in array

public int[] mymethod()
{

   return arr;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There is no need to duplicate other answers. Especially on a question answered 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to copy?

```
int[] myArray = method();  // now myArray can be used
```