# method changing array length with array return type in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method in my code that takes an `array` and returns that array with a larger size.
How could I use this method on non static arrays?
I'm confused because I think arrays always have a specific length and simply making my array, and the one returned from the method, point to one place of memory using the "=" sign can't do it...
I'd appreciate it if you refer me to some examples of methods working with arrays.

```
public static int[] shift (int []A, final int n)
{
    int []temp;
    temp = new int[A.length];
    temp = A;
    A = new int[A.length+n];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, A, 0, A.length);

    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    A[A.length+i] = 0;}

    return A;
}
```

This is a method for example, and in another method I want to make an array to use the returned one.

```
int []B = new int[1];
B[0]=1;
int []C = new int[n];

C = shift(B,10);
```

Comment: Can you add the actual code you're referring too? It's kind of difficult to understand without it.

Comment: [how to store an array returned by a method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378756/how-to-store-an-array-returned-by-a-method-in-java)
I guess that post can answer you question.

Comment: thanks,i got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Default arrays in java are static and you can't anyhow change that behaviour. However there are many classes in util package extenting List class that can be used for dynamic array purposes. One of them is ArrayLis as @JoseCifuentes said.

Comment: so  when I have a method with array return type it has to be static?

Comment: I didn't mean static as an access modifier but as a fixed size array

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of an array. You can only reassign the reference:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
// 'arr' is reference to a new array size 5, in the free store.

arr = new int[10];
// 'arr' is reference to a new array size 10, in the free store. First array is deallocated.
```

The first array and all it's contents is destroyed when you reassign `arr`.

However, the java API has a method to create a new array of specified length and copy all the elements of the old: `Arrays.copOf`

You could use it like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 10); // new size is 10
```

Note that `copyOf` either truncates the array or pads with `null` (or `0` in case of `int`). See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

did you checked this code before posting here?

```
 for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
A[A.length+i] = 0;}
```

out of bounds exception.

let's say that A.length=2 and n=2. then the new A length is 4.

next we get to the for part, there you trying to do A[A.length+i] when A.length equal to 4 and i equal to 1 you trying to reach A[5] but A got just 4 cells, 0-3.

Comment: nope,i just wanted to show an example,actually my question is how does the methods with array return work?if I make the array static then returning is not needed cause it has changed already.

Comment: when you return an array you actually return reference to the array. Then you can save the reference like "int [] a= {1}; a = shift(a,1);" then a will point to the arr that shift return.