# return new int[]{randomHeight, randomWidth};

Tags: java, minesweeper

I want to code some basic stuff for a little minesweeper-game, that we do in university. Now I have the problem that my code .

```
public class Minesweeper1 {

    public static int[][]  makeRandomBoard(int s, int z, int n){
        //creating the field and fill with 0
        int feld[][] = new int [s][z];
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < z; j++){
                feld[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        //n-times to fill the field
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            selectRandomPosition(s, z);
            //want to get them from selectRandomPosition
            feld[randomHeight][randomWidth] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

So it starts the `selectRandomPosition` code:

```
public static int[] selectRandomPosition(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    int randomHeight = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxHeight);
    int randomWidth = StdRandom.uniform(0, maxWidth);
    return new int[]{randomHeight, randomWidth};
}
```

Here I'm not allowed to change anything, but it returns a new array. Now is my question how can I use the new array in my `makeRandomBoard` method, since I do not know any name of the array. When I use `feld[randomHeight][randomWidth] = 1;`, it says that it doesn't know these variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store an array returned by a method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378756/how-to-store-an-array-returned-by-a-method-in-java)

Comment: `randomHeight` and `randomWidth` a local variables of `selectRandomPosition` function. you cannot use these variables outside this funcion.

Comment: @mcNets I know that, but my question was how I get them there without a name of the array, since we did not had that in any lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can use the new array in my `makeRandomBoard` method, since I do not know any name of the array?

Call the method, and assign its return value to a variable. Now you have a name for the array:

```
// Make a call
int[] randomArray = selectRandomPosition(maxW, maxH);
// Access the width
int randomW = randomArray[0];
// Access the height
int randomH = randomArray[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, never thaught about that :D